# How to store user data on Heroku

Tags: facebook, heroku

I'm making a Facebook app that runs on Heroku. The app will send data to the Heroku server where it will be stored. Preferably it will store this data in a text file, because that seems to be the easiest way.

Can this be done? I know that Heroku lets you store data in some kind of database but that seems more than necessary.

Comment: it depends on your server-side programing language

Comment: as heroku instance is readonly so its not possible to write any thing there ... wither its php or rails we need to shift our files to other storage services like s3

Comment: So PHP can be used on a Heroku server to save a text file to S3?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it can be done, but as a db not as a flat file.

Read up on the PostgreSQL here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

Why not a flat file?  http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem

Because the file system is read-only. And Heroku recommends you use the PostgreSQL for data storage.

Comment: javascript ninja, I don't know what S3 is, I don't even know Heroku.  I did a quickie Google search and saw the documentation that applies to your situation and posted the links here with a quick synopsis.  Happy coding.